# Two sets of minipages not aligned

Tags: minipage

[image]

I have two `minipage`s side by side, the first defined at width 5cm, the second, width 6cm.

I then have some text below these two. Following this text I have another two `minipage`s with the same specifications. Unfortunately the text on each left and right `minipage` does not line up with that of the respective one below. I'm sure this is due to the length of text in each respective `minipage`, however I would ideally like the left `minipage`s to be right justified to the same position, and the same for the right hand `minipage`s (left justified).

Is this possible?

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\begin{align*}
A_2 = x_1A_1 \therefore 
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{9cm}
\begin{align*}
& x_1 = 1  
\stepcounter{equation}\tag{1}\\
& x_1 = 5/2
\stepcounter{equation}\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%

These values of $x_1$ are not consistent and therefore second asset is linearly independent. To test the third asset, assume that:

\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\begin{align*}
A_3 = x_1A_1 + x_2A_2 \therefore \\
2 * (1) \\
3 * (1)
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{9cm}
\begin{align*}
& x_1 + x_2 = 2
\stepcounter{equation}\tag{1}\\
& 2x_1 + 5x_2 = 2
\stepcounter{equation}\tag{2}\\
& 3x_1 + 4x_2 = 37
\stepcounter{equation}\tag{3}\\
& 2x_1+2x_2 = 4 
\stepcounter{equation}\tag{4}\\
& x_2 = -3/2\\
& 3x_1 + 3x_2 = 6
\stepcounter{equation}\tag{5}\\
& x_2 = 31\\
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
```

Comment: No `minipage`s but use `align` from `amsmath`.

Comment: Welcome! Please make your code compilable. You are much more likely to get really effective help if you do!

Comment: why are you using `align*` and then using `\stepcounter` ? That's just weird.

Answer (score 4):

Use `align` from `amsmath` and let latex do work for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
 \begin{align}
A_2 = x_1A_1 \qquad \therefore \quad
& x_1 = 1\\
& x_1 = 5/2
\end{align}
These values of $x_1$ are not consistent and therefore second asset is linearly independent. To test the third asset, assume that:
\begin{align}
A_3 = x_1A_1 + x_2A_2 \qquad \therefore \quad
& x_1 + x_2 = 2 \label{eq:myeq}\\
& 2x_1 + 5x_2 = 2\\
& 3x_1 + 4x_2 = 37\\[1ex]
2 \times \text{equation~\ref{eq:myeq}} \phantom{\qquad{}\therefore{}\quad} & 2x_1+2x_2 = 4\\
& x_2 = -3/2 \notag\\[1ex]
3 \times \text{equation~\ref{eq:myeq}} \phantom{\qquad{}\therefore{}\quad} & 3x_1 + 3x_2 = 6\\
& x_2 = 31 \notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the alignment needs to persist across, then use only a single `align` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
 \begin{align}
A_2 = x_1A_1 \qquad \therefore \quad
& x_1 = 1\\
& x_1 = 5/2
\intertext{These values of $x_1$ are not consistent and therefore second asset is linearly independent. To test the third asset, assume that:}
A_3 = x_1A_1 + x_2A_2 \qquad \therefore \quad
& x_1 + x_2 = 2 \label{eq:myeq}\\
& 2x_1 + 5x_2 = 2\\
& 3x_1 + 4x_2 = 37\\[1ex]
2 \times \text{equation~\ref{eq:myeq}} \phantom{\qquad{}\therefore{}\quad} & 2x_1+2x_2 = 4\\
& x_2 = -3/2 \notag\\[1ex]
3 \times \text{equation~\ref{eq:myeq}} \phantom{\qquad{}\therefore{}\quad} & 3x_1 + 3x_2 = 6\\
& x_2 = 31 \notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for this, much simpler. I do notice however that the set of minipages below are JUST a little to the right of those above.

Comment: There is no alignment specified between the top and bottom, if the OP needs that then it should be a single `align` then `\intertext` for the intervening text.

Comment: @FeersumEndjinn: Please see the edit.